# How to increase the number of points on the fitted curve of a histgoram?

Tags: histogram, curve-fitting, curvesmoothing

I have a histogram in MATLAB and would like to make a fit to it. I can do it using histfit but I kept getting a fitted curve of fixed size, which is 100. I mean there are always 100 points given on the curve. How do I change this? I want to increase the number of points to make the fitted curve smoother? In addition I don't have curve fitting toolbox in my MATLAB.
I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Take the result of the fit (i.e. the curve) and evaluate it manually at as many points as you wish.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by evaluating manually in detail?